# column dates to quarters with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with these columns (important part is that i have every month from 1996-04 to 2016-08)

```
Index(['RegionID', 'RegionName', 'State', 'Metro', 'CountyName', 'SizeRank',
'1996-04', '1996-05', '1996-06', '1996-07',
 ...
'2015-11', '2015-12', '2016-01', '2016-02', '2016-03', '2016-04',
'2016-05', '2016-06', '2016-07', '2016-08'],
dtype='object', length=251)
```

I need to group columns by three to represent financial quarters, eg:

```
| 1998-01 | 1999-02 | 1999-03 |
|    2    |    4    |    7    |
```

Needs to become

```
|  1998q1  |
|avg(2,4,7)|
```

Any hint about the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convert all  non dates columns to index, convert them to `quarter period` and aggregate by columns with `mean`:

```
df = df.set_index(['RegionID', 'RegionName', 'State', 'Metro', 'CountyName', 'SizeRank'])
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period('Q').strftime('%Yq%q')
df = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).mean().reset_index()
```

Comment: This converts to 2000Q1 and not to 2000q1

Comment: @MilesDavis - use `df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period('Q').strftime('%Yq%q')`